# Selectin only the begenning of a range in excel to input in a sum

Tags: excel, sum, range

I am trying to do a sum over the first "a" element of this range:
[image]

The aim is to keep the range B3 to F3 in the formula but somehow introduce the input from cell B4 to tell the sumto stop summing after the the "a"-th column of the range (for this example the third column). My initially idea was to use offset function but the issue is it would shift to the the left by three and consider column A which I do not want. Any idea on how I could to that in a clever way?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One option, using `INDEX`:

```
=SUM(B3:INDEX(B3:F3,,B4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`OFFSET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) for that:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B3;0;0;1;B4))
```

[image]

Comment: One note about OFFSET:  It is a volatile function.  Meaning that it will recaclulate when ever excel recalcs.  non volatile functions only recalc if the data to which they are directed changes.  Volatile functions should be used sparingly.

Comment: ^^^ and not at all when there is a non-volitile alternative available